# QFN VS MSOP- Which is better for thermal performance

Tags: power-supply, pcb, buck, thermal

I am having to decide between a MSOP package and a QFN package for a Buck controller that I am designing in. The Part number is LTC3603. The MSOP is called an eMSOP. I cant locate any further information on what is the difference between MSOP and eMSOP. What are some of the pros and cons of each package. Right off the bat the big flip side of using a QFN is the lack of ease for rework. A MSOP is leaded and hence can be replaced easily without a hot air rework station.

Answer (score 3):

> Which is better for thermal performance[?]

\$\theta_{JC}\$ and \$\theta_{JA}\$ values are given in the "Pin Configuration" drawings on page 2 of the [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3603fc.pdf).

The QFN package has lower values.

**From your comment**

> What else can I do from the PCB design standpoint to augument the thermal performance

To minimize \$\theta_{JA}\$, you can

- provide multiple vias from the exposed pad to ground planes
- use heavy copper on the ground planes
- add ground fill on top and bottom layer (and connect it well to your hot chip and the buried planes)
- Provide forced air movement over the board
- Arrange chips so that hot chips are nearest the source of air flow, and air doesn't flow over one hot chip to another one
- ...

Comment: Thanks. What else can I do from the PCB design standpoint to augument the thermal performance apart from choosing a QFN packagae that has lower Junction to case and junction to ambient. Any thoughts?